# .htaccess redirect from root to html saving all links

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a `localhost/news_back` url (My php script is here)
And I have a `localhost/news_back/client/admin.html`
I need to redirect every user, coming to my host to `admin.html`. 
It means that user must see in his adress bar this:

http://localhost/news_back/client/admin.html

It also means, that all scripts and img sources in my html must work correctly.
And all my POST and GET requests must save their urls.

Everything I've tried changes paths or leads to errors.

Comment: Can we please see what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys, thanks for your advices, but my hosting provider has offered a solution,  this helped!
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[mydomain].com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.[mydomain].com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://aranews.blogjist.com/client/admin.html [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. may help you....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/news_back/client/admin.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still getting directory content.

Comment: Ok, My .htaccess file now looks like:
`RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/news_back/client/admin.html [R=301,L]
directory browsing Options All -Indexes`
Still getting the directory.

Comment: # directory browsing is comment, so remove it.

Comment: There is no "#" symbol before directory browsing Options All -Indexes line in my file

Comment: use `Options  All -Indexes` instead of `directory browsing Options All -Indexes`